# Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

Tags: android, react-native, expo, okhttp

I developed an application that through some requests by AXIOS to certain apis it presents data, the app is very simple, I have checked all links and they all start with HTTP or HTTPS .. The application works perfectly if I generate the apk in DEBUG mode , but if I create an apk release the error comes ...

it is worth mentioning that this is a project ejected from the expo

this is the logcat log when i open the app release:

```
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.radarcorona, PID: 10873
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1333)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:916)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:165)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.updates.loader.FileDownloader.addHeadersToManifestUrl(FileDownloader.java:190)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.updates.loader.FileDownloader.downloadManifest(FileDownloader.java:79)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.updates.loader.RemoteLoader.start(RemoteLoader.java:56)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.lambda$start$0$UpdatesController(UpdatesController.java:307)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at expo.modules.updates.-$$Lambda$UpdatesController$cVwvsx9XXcX6YuWbf7IvrVkJAiA.run(Unknown Source:6)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-20 23:11:18.022 10873 10896 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-20 23:11:18.024 10873 10894 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-20 23:11:18.036  2039  2882 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.radarcorona/.MainActivity
```

react-native:  0.61.5

Comment: You'll need to post some of your relevant code, it looks like you have a wrong URL somewhere.

Comment: @JuanMartinez but why does this only appear when generating an apk release? because when I generate a debug apk everything works

Comment: Do you have different configs for dev/prod?

Comment: @iuliu.net 
As far as I know, I only use the standard that came, the only thing I changed was the keystore, but I tested it without and the error follows, it seems that it is some process that occurs in the build release that messes up the links

Comment: @FhDev Did you figure out how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @LukasGjetting did you find a solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution to this error.

1. Removing `expo-updates`.  As @fabiocosta88 mentioned on [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7935), the issue raises from `expo-updates`.  Since I wasn't actually using the module in my project, I followed the guide to remove the module in all files it was defined. Here is the [guide](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-updates/).
2. If uninstallation is not an option I believe that defining the `EXPO_UPDATE_URL` and `EXPO_SDK_VERSION` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` might solve the issue. I believe this [guide](https://docs.expo.io/bare/updating-your-app/) defines how to get the `EXPO_UPDATE_URL`.